# How do you read vertex/index buffers?

Tags: c++, directx-12

Basically, my question is: how do you read vertex/index buffers in DirectX 12? I guess I am looking for something equivalent to DirectX 11's map function, which I understand now you have to do manually. I tried googling for the answer, but didn't find anything. There aren't many DirectX 12 examples/tutorials since it is pretty new.

Comment: DirectX has always been pretty badly documented.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't read back GPU resources as it's poor performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another buffer resource with the heap type set to `D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_READBACK`. Copy the vertex/index buffer to the new resource using `ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::CopyBufferRegion` or [`UpdateSubresources`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn899213(v=vs.85).aspx). After the copy operation is complete, call `ID3D12Resource::Map` to see the results.

For more information, read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn899202(v=vs.85).aspx).